# Connecting a ring terminal to a smaller stud

Tags: wiring, terminal

[This 12V DC breaker panel](https://www.bluesea.com/products/8023/Traditional_Metal_DC_Panel_-_8_Positions) is meant to carry up to 100A, but provides a fairly small stud for terminal connection.  The product documentation doesn't appear to indicate the stud size; it was measured with a caliper at 3/16" (#10).  The product manual itself recommends use of 2 AWG wire, for which [ring terminals/lugs smaller than 1/4" do not appear to be manufactured](http://www.ancorproducts.com/en/products/terminals/heavy-duty-lugs/2-awg).

Is it generally safe to use a 1/4" ring terminal on a 3/16" stud?  Are there any special considerations?  If I were to add a flat washer to stabilize the connection, how would I know what material it should be made from?

Comment: A material that conducts i.e. metal, so brass, steel, copper (but this work hardens) but not plastic...

Answer (score 1):

Automotive starter motors aud alternators use copper washers on their high current stud terminals, So it'd go with that.

Comment: Would I need to worry about galvanic corrosion if the other hardware is made of a different metal?